# Limit a has-many relationship by the parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.6, a `user has_many posts` where a post can be `public` or `private`.  I need to return a list of users joined to their posts *where the user has > 0 public posts* and limit the records returned based on the `user` while also limiting the number of joined `posts`.

As an example represented as a mock ORM:

```
// User A has 4 public posts
// User B has 0 public posts
// User C has 1 public post
// User D has 5 public posts

// I am limiting the posts fetched per-user to 3 and the users fetched to 2:

[
  {
    user: "A",
    posts: [
      { id: 10 },
      { id: 28 },
      { id: 33 }
      // Fourth post omitted since we are limiting per-user to 3
    ]
  },
  // B is skipped since they have no posts
  {
    user: "C",
    posts: [
      { id: 45 }
    ]
  }
  // D is skipped because we are limiting total users to 2
]
```

I was able to get it working as expected with the exception of being able to limit posts returned per user with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts
ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.id IN (
    SELECT users.id
    FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts
    ON posts.user_id = users.id AND posts.visibility = "public"
    GROUP BY users.id
    HAVING COUNT(posts.id) > 0
    LIMIT 1 -- Limits users fetched regardless of how many posts, but doesn't limit posts fetched themselves
)
```

But this feels needlessly complex while it doesn't even solve the problem correctly.  Since we're using Postgres, I had a few attempts involving a `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL` which seemed promising for limiting per-user posts, but left me stumped when it came to setting a limit of users to return.

Comment: `LIMIT`ing without `ORDER`ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: There would be an order, but I'm trying to keep this to a minimal example

Answer (score 1):

You can do (assuming `posts` has a column named `id`):

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number(partition by p.user_id order by p.id) as rn
  from users u
  join posts p on p.user_id = u.id
  where u.user_id in (
    select user_id
    from (select distinct user_id from posts where visibility = 'public') x
    order by user_id
    limit 2 -- limits users to 2 (with public posts)
  )
) y
where rn <= 3 -- limits posts per user to 3
```

Performance can be improved when the posts are massive in number and most of them are public posts by the use of a lateral table expression.